# `muse-publish-this-file` makes Emacs hang and use 95% of my RAM

Tags: muse

I'm editing a large book in one file (78K according to Emacs; should I divide each chapter in files instead?), when I call `muse-publish-this-file` it makes Emacs hangs (to not respond, unless I press <kbd>C-</kbd><kbd>g</kbd>), when this command is execute the RAM use of Emacs grows to 95%!

I just have this in my Emacs configuration regarding Muse:

```
(require 'muse-mode)
(require 'muse-docbook)
(require 'muse-project)
```

I also have DocBook installed on my GNU/Linux machine:

```
~ > LC_ALL=C pacman -Qs docbook                                                                                                             
local/docbook-xml 4.5-6
    A widely used XML scheme for writing documentation and help
local/docbook-xsl 1.78.1-1
    XML stylesheets for Docbook-xml transformations
~ >
```

I'm not using/defining a Muse project since I'm putting everything in one file.

I have noticed that the amount of RAM doesn't decrease if I stop the command, only after I close Emacs the amount of RAM in use go back to normal.

Here is the **Backtrace** using `toggle-debug-on-quit` and quitting after reproducing the hang.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
  looking-at("^\\(<\\(/?\\)quote>\\)")
  #[(indent) "\301 \210\302\225b\210`dW\205�\303!?\207" [quote-regexp muse-forward-paragraph 0 looking-at] 2]("[[:blank:]]+")
  muse-publish-surround-text("<para>" "</para>" #[(indent) "\301 \210\302\225b\210`dW\205�\303!?\207" [quote-regexp muse-forward-paragraph 0 looking-at] 2] nil nil nil "^\\(<\\(/?\\)quote>\\)")
  muse-publish-quote-tag(44306 #<marker at 5860133 in  *muse-temp*>)
  apply(muse-publish-quote-tag (44306 #<marker at 5860133 in  *muse-temp*>))
  muse-publish-markup-tag()
  muse-publish-markup("en donde dice la biblia que" ((1000 "\\(\\`\n+\\|\n+\\'\\)" 0 "") (1100 "[[:blank:]]+$" 0 "") (1200 "\\`#\\([a-zA-Z-]+\\)\\s-+\\(.+\\)\n+" 0 directive) (1250 "^;\\(?:[[:blank:]]+\\(.+\\)\\|$\\|'\\)" 0 comment) (1300 muse-tag-regexp 0 tag) (1400 muse-explicit-link-regexp 0 muse-publish-mark-link) (1600 "\\(^\\|[-[[:blank:]<('`\"\n]\\)\\(=[^=[:blank:]\n]\\|_[^_[:blank:]\n]\\|\\*+[^*[:blank:]\n]\\)" 2 word) (1700 "^\\(\\*+\\)\\s-+" 0 heading) (1800 "\\.\\.\\.\\." 0 enddots) (1850 "\\.\\.\\." 0 dots) (1900 "^----+" 0 rule) (1950 "~~" 0 no-break-space) (2000 "^Footnotes:?\\s-*" 0 fn-sep) (2100 "\\[\\([1-9][0-9]*\\)\\]" 0 footnote) (2200 "^[[:blank:]]*\\(\\([^\n[:blank:]].*?\\)?::\\(?:[[:blank:]]+\\|$\\)\\|[[:blank:]]-[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]][0-9]+\\.[[:blank:]]*\\)" 0 list) (2300 "^[[:blank:]]*\\+\\(-*\\+\\)+[[:blank:]]*\n\\(\\([[:blank:]]*|\\(.*|\\)*[[:blank:]]*\n\\)+\\([[:blank:]]*\\+\\(-*\\+\\)+[[:blank:]]*\\)\\(\n\\|\\'\\)\\)+" 0 table-el) (2350 "\\(\\([[:blank:]]*\n\\)?\\(\\(?:.*[[:blank:]]+\\(|+\\)\\(?:[[:blank:]]\\|$\\).*\\|[[:blank:]]*|[-+]+|[[:blank:]]*\\)\\(?:\n\\|\\'\\)\\)\\)+" 0 table) (2400 "^\\([[:blank:]]+\\).+" 0 quote) (2500 "\\(^\\|[[:blank:]]*\\)---?\\($\\|[[:blank:]]*\\)" 0 emdash) (2600 "^[[:blank:]]*> " 0 verse) (2700 "^\\(\\W*\\)#\\(\\S-+\\)\\s-*" 0 anchor) (2900 muse-explicit-link-regexp 0 link) (3000 muse-url-regexp 0 url) (3500 "\\([^[]\\)[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+@\\([-a-zA-z0-9_]+\\.\\)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+" 0 email) (10000 "\\(\\(\n\\(?:[[:blank:]]*\n\\)*\\([[:blank:]]*\n\\)\\)\\|\\`\\s-*\\|\\s-*\\'\\)" 3 muse-docbook-markup-paragraph)))
  muse-publish-markup-region(1 78473 "en donde dice la biblia que" ("docbook" :suffix muse-docbook-extension :regexps muse-docbook-markup-regexps :functions muse-docbook-markup-functions :strings muse-docbook-markup-strings :specials muse-xml-decide-specials :before-end muse-docbook-munge-buffer :after muse-docbook-finalize-buffer :header muse-docbook-header :footer muse-docbook-footer :browser find-file))
  muse-publish-markup-buffer("en donde dice la biblia que" ("docbook" :suffix muse-docbook-extension :regexps muse-docbook-markup-regexps :functions muse-docbook-markup-functions :strings muse-docbook-markup-strings :specials muse-xml-decide-specials :before-end muse-docbook-munge-buffer :after muse-docbook-finalize-buffer :header muse-docbook-header :footer muse-docbook-footer :browser find-file))
  byte-code("rq\210\306 !\210\307\310!\210\n\203�\311 \210\312\313\314  !\f\"\210)\315
!\203,�\316\317\f   
%\210)\306\207" [temp-buffer file muse-publish-enable-local-variables muse-inhibit-before-publish-hook style output-path muse-insert-file-contents run-hooks muse-before-publish-hook hack-local-variables t muse-publish-markup-buffer muse-page-name muse-write-file muse-style-run-hooks :final target] 6)
  muse-publish-file("/home/jorge/Documentos/en donde dice la biblia que.muse" ("docbook" :suffix muse-docbook-extension :regexps muse-docbook-markup-regexps :functions muse-docbook-markup-functions :strings muse-docbook-markup-strings :specials muse-xml-decide-specials :before-end muse-docbook-munge-buffer :after muse-docbook-finalize-buffer :header muse-docbook-header :footer muse-docbook-footer :browser find-file) "/home/jorge/Documentos/" nil)
  muse-publish-this-file(("docbook" :suffix muse-docbook-extension :regexps muse-docbook-markup-regexps :functions muse-docbook-markup-functions :strings muse-docbook-markup-strings :specials muse-xml-decide-specials :before-end muse-docbook-munge-buffer :after muse-docbook-finalize-buffer :header muse-docbook-header :footer muse-docbook-footer :browser find-file) "/home/jorge/Documentos/" nil)
  call-interactively(muse-publish-this-file record nil)
  command-execute(muse-publish-this-file record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "muse-publish-this-file")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

**EDIT:** seems like Muse cannot export the quote tag to docbook. I have a large quote in the document, and since I changed the tags to `verse` I can export to docbook correctly (however, the RAM use by Emacs don't decrease after exporting). If I change the quote content with a couple of lines and try to export, this error is yelled by Emacs:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range -1 -1)
  replace-match("" t t nil 1)
  muse-publish-surround-text("<para>" "</para>" #[(indent) "\301 \210\302\225b\210`dW\205�\303!?\207" [quote-regexp muse-forward-paragraph 0 looking-at] 2] nil nil nil "^\\(<\\(/?\\)quote>\\)")
  muse-publish-quote-tag(44306 #<marker at 44376 in  *muse-temp*-62374>)
  apply(muse-publish-quote-tag (44306 #<marker at 44376 in  *muse-temp*-62374>))
  muse-publish-markup-tag()
  muse-publish-markup("prueba1" ((1000 "\\(\\`\n+\\|\n+\\'\\)" 0 "") (1100 "[[:blank:]]+$" 0 "") (1200 "\\`#\\([a-zA-Z-]+\\)\\s-+\\(.+\\)\n+" 0 directive) (1250 "^;\\(?:[[:blank:]]+\\(.+\\)\\|$\\|'\\)" 0 comment) (1300 muse-tag-regexp 0 tag) (1400 muse-explicit-link-regexp 0 muse-publish-mark-link) (1600 "\\(^\\|[-[[:blank:]<('`\"\n]\\)\\(=[^=[:blank:]\n]\\|_[^_[:blank:]\n]\\|\\*+[^*[:blank:]\n]\\)" 2 word) (1700 "^\\(\\*+\\)\\s-+" 0 heading) (1800 "\\.\\.\\.\\." 0 enddots) (1850 "\\.\\.\\." 0 dots) (1900 "^----+" 0 rule) (1950 "~~" 0 no-break-space) (2000 "^Footnotes:?\\s-*" 0 fn-sep) (2100 "\\[\\([1-9][0-9]*\\)\\]" 0 footnote) (2200 "^[[:blank:]]*\\(\\([^\n[:blank:]].*?\\)?::\\(?:[[:blank:]]+\\|$\\)\\|[[:blank:]]-[[:blank:]]*\\|[[:blank:]][0-9]+\\.[[:blank:]]*\\)" 0 list) (2300 "^[[:blank:]]*\\+\\(-*\\+\\)+[[:blank:]]*\n\\(\\([[:blank:]]*|\\(.*|\\)*[[:blank:]]*\n\\)+\\([[:blank:]]*\\+\\(-*\\+\\)+[[:blank:]]*\\)\\(\n\\|\\'\\)\\)+" 0 table-el) (2350 "\\(\\([[:blank:]]*\n\\)?\\(\\(?:.*[[:blank:]]+\\(|+\\)\\(?:[[:blank:]]\\|$\\).*\\|[[:blank:]]*|[-+]+|[[:blank:]]*\\)\\(?:\n\\|\\'\\)\\)\\)+" 0 table) (2400 "^\\([[:blank:]]+\\).+" 0 quote) (2500 "\\(^\\|[[:blank:]]*\\)---?\\($\\|[[:blank:]]*\\)" 0 emdash) (2600 "^[[:blank:]]*> " 0 verse) (2700 "^\\(\\W*\\)#\\(\\S-+\\)\\s-*" 0 anchor) (2900 muse-explicit-link-regexp 0 link) (3000 muse-url-regexp 0 url) (3500 "\\([^[]\\)[-a-zA-Z0-9._]+@\\([-a-zA-z0-9_]+\\.\\)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+" 0 email) (10000 "\\(\\(\n\\(?:[[:blank:]]*\n\\)*\\([[:blank:]]*\n\\)\\)\\|\\`\\s-*\\|\\s-*\\'\\)" 3 muse-docbook-markup-paragraph)))
  muse-publish-markup-region(1 44459 "prueba1" ("docbook" :suffix muse-docbook-extension :regexps muse-docbook-markup-regexps :functions muse-docbook-markup-functions :strings muse-docbook-markup-strings :specials muse-xml-decide-specials :before-end muse-docbook-munge-buffer :after muse-docbook-finalize-buffer :header muse-docbook-header :footer muse-docbook-footer :browser find-file))
  muse-publish-markup-buffer("prueba1" ("docbook" :suffix muse-docbook-extension :regexps muse-docbook-markup-regexps :functions muse-docbook-markup-functions :strings muse-docbook-markup-strings :specials muse-xml-decide-specials :before-end muse-docbook-munge-buffer :after muse-docbook-finalize-buffer :header muse-docbook-header :footer muse-docbook-footer :browser find-file))
  muse-publish-file("/tmp/prueba1.muse" ("docbook" :suffix muse-docbook-extension :regexps muse-docbook-markup-regexps :functions muse-docbook-markup-functions :strings muse-docbook-markup-strings :specials muse-xml-decide-specials :before-end muse-docbook-munge-buffer :after muse-docbook-finalize-buffer :header muse-docbook-header :footer muse-docbook-footer :browser find-file) "/tmp/" nil)
  muse-publish-this-file(("docbook" :suffix muse-docbook-extension :regexps muse-docbook-markup-regexps :functions muse-docbook-markup-functions :strings muse-docbook-markup-strings :specials muse-xml-decide-specials :before-end muse-docbook-munge-buffer :after muse-docbook-finalize-buffer :header muse-docbook-header :footer muse-docbook-footer :browser find-file) "/tmp/" nil)
  call-interactively(muse-publish-this-file record nil)
  command-execute(muse-publish-this-file record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "muse-publish-this-file")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

I should mark the quotes with another method in the meanwhile...

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`. Reproduce the hang. Hit `C-g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a bug with muse exporting to docbook and the `<quote>` tag when the quote content is large, I have already [reported it to the Muse developers](http://gna.org/bugs/?22924). in the meantime I'll use just a [whitespace before the line to denote a quote](http://mwolson.org/projects/MuseQuickStart.html#sec6) allowing me to export my book.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to separate out (remove) everything you can that might not be relevant. Get rid of using the hook, for now, to see if that makes a difference. If it makes no difference, remove it from your problem description.

What happens when you use a smaller book?

What do you think having DocBook installed has to do with this problem? What happens if you use a document that is not docbook XML, i.e., if you do not use `muse-docbook`.

Is `muse-project` needed, to reproduce the problem?

In sum, simplify, to break the problem down and discover what the real problem is. As it stands now, you have a lot of stuff in a big sack, you throw the sack up in the air, and you say "What's wrong?".  Trim down your problem search space.

Comment: In a fairly tiny file (107 bytes) the command works as it should, generating an xml file.

Comment: So work your way up to the problematic case. Split what you did before in two: do half of it. If you removed some stuff, as I suggested, then try adding some or all of it back, still with a small file. If you did not, then try a file with size halfway between. Or try [profiling](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html#Profiling) the relevant code, to see which part is slow. Or contact the Muse author/maintainer, and ask for advice. But first narrow things down, so you can report just where the problem is.

Comment: the problem appears when the file reaches 48KB, at 44KB the file is exported correctly. Is this a bug, maybe?

Comment: There is probably no way for people here to know whether this is a bug. If Emacs really *hangs* then it might well be a bug. If Emacs is just slow, then there might be a bug (perhaps Muse doesn't scale well because of a bug). Or there might not: perhaps this is a known limitation of the Muse design or implementation. Unless you find some Muse expert here who can help, your best bet is to contact the Muse maintainer. Or you can try working around the problem, as you mentioned: perhaps separate chapter files helps.